# How to force Eclipse Link creates Tables exactly same ClassName?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'd like JPA EclipseLink creates tables exactly as is the ClassName (and fields) WITHOUT annotation @Table and @Column. It's always creates tables and fields with UPPERCASE, which makes readability difficult in the DB console.

ex.:

```
@Entity
public class ChannelEntity {
    
    @Id     @GeneratedValue  
    public Long id;
    
    public String name;
    
    public String description;
    
    public Boolean oficial;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date creation;

}
```

And I'd like results in

```
    Table: ChannelEntity
    id  creation    description name        oficial
   ----------------------------------------------------
    351 NULL        meu desc    meu nome    1
```

Maybe exist same parameter in persistence.xml, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

If EclipseLink behaves correctly, the parameter you are looking for is `delimited-identifers`. From the JPA 2.1 spec:

> It is possible to specify that all database identifiers in use for a
>   persistence unit be treated as delimited identifiers by specifying the
>   `<delimited-identifiers/>` element within the `persistence-unit-defaults`
>   element of the object/relational xml mapping file. If the
>   `<delimited-identifiers/>` element is specified, it cannot be
>   overridden.

If this element is included, EclipseLink should delimit all database identifiers in its generated SQL, which would cause the database objects to be created with case-sensitive names.